# Does Dragonball super have only 1 underworld? Or one per universe?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

One thing I'm not sure about with the introduction of the different universes is: Does Dragonball super have only 1 underworld/afterlife? Or 1 per universe?

Comment: If each universe has their own Kaioshins and God of Destruction, why wouldn't they have their own Hell?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that each universe has its own heaven and hell. We know that a universe is divided into four quadrants and each has its own Kai. Then there is the Grand Kai who governs them. After that we have the Supreme Kai who looks over the entire *afterlife* and the *universe*.

There is an extensive system of Kais to govern the entire universe, including the afterlife. It can be concluded that because each universe has its own Supreme Kai (and of course, the God of Destruction), it also has its own underworld.

Comment: I seem to recall Goku and the others telling Frieza its his own fault for coming to Earth for wherever he ended up (for him, it was hell, but where specifically was directly due to him being on earth). I do recall Earth has its own afterlife checkpoint. It seems oddly specific to Earth, so there is pretty good evidence its at least one per universe, though it could be more than one.